# Jquery select of Telerik numeric text box value

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have MVC 5 views with one or more Telerik numeric text boxes that each render like:

```
<span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox">
<span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default">
    <input tabindex="0" class="k-formatted-value k-input" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;" type="text">
    <input name="SelectedMinimumChange" class="k-input" id="SelectedMinimumChange" role="spinbutton" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="5" aria-valuemax="95" style="display: none;" type="text" min="5" max="95" step="5" value="10" data-role="numerictextbox">
    <span class="k-select">
        <span class="k-link" style="-ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom pinch-zoom;" unselectable="on">
            <span title="Increase value" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" unselectable="on">Increase value
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="k-link" style="-ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom pinch-zoom;" unselectable="on">
            <span title="Decrease value" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">Decrease value
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

My task is to get the selected value(s), which are in the second input tag, held in the attribute 'value' (in this sample it is 10) and hide the controls

Getting the controls are easy enough (even for me):

```
$(".k-numerictextbox").each(function () {
      var control = $(this);
      …     try to get the value
      Control.hide();
});
```

This finds and hides the controls.  I can get the value of the specific control with:

```
var displayVal = input.data("kendoNumericTextBox").value()
```

But my attempts to string together enough JQuery selectors has not worked.  I need to go from the control to the child with class “k-input” (there are 2) then the child with the attribute [data-role] = ‘numerictextbox’ then get the value of the attribute value there.  I tried [a lot of things] inside the each loop - my final:

```
var displayVal = control.children(".k-input").find("[data-role]='numerictextbox'")
```

feels like it's on the right track but I can’t figure out who to add the next selector to get the result.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go from the inside out - here's what worked:

```
        $("input[type=text][id][data-role=numerictextbox]").each(function () {
        var input = $(this); //the element within the numerictextbox with the id
        var id = input.attr("id"); //get the id
        var control = $("#" + id).data("kendoNumericTextBox"); //get the kendo control from the id
        var displayVal = control.value(); //the value we want to display
        var displayElem = $("<span />"); //new display element
        displayElem.text(displayVal);
        var topControlElement = input.closest(".k-numerictextbox"); //get the root element making up the kendo numerictextbox
        displayElem.insertBefore(topControlElement);
        control.destroy();
        topControlElement.remove();
    });
```